# Gradle GebConfig.groovy parameterized

Tags: gradle, geb

I want to paramaterize GebConfig.groovy such that I can specify a RemoteWebDriver url.

I am using Gradle as my build tool.

My GebConfig.groovy looks like

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver

driver = {
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox()
   new RemoteWebDriver(
     new URL("http://xx:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities
   )
}
```

What I want to do is to say

```
new URL(project.remoteURL)
```

Where remoteURL is passed in via the command like like

```
gradle test -PremoteURL=http://xx:4444/wd/hub
```

Is this do-able? How does GebConfig.groovy get a reference to the Gradle project? Or is there a alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be fairly simple. First, pass the url from project property to a system property in the test JVM in your `build.gradle`:

```
test {
    systemProperty "com.example.test.remoteWebDriverUrl", project.remoteURL
}
```

And then use it in `GebConfig.groovy` to create a `RemoteWebDriver` instance.

```
driver = {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox()
    URL url = new URL(System.getProperty("com.example.test.remoteWebDriverUrl")
    new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities)
}
```