# How to override value which set in Groovy config to value from Jenkins build parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, config, geb

For now I have a `config.properties` file and a singleton configuration object, which reads the file to a map and then puts all the system variables there as well. So when I run my tests via Jenkins, job's parameters with the same name will override values, set in `config.properties` file.

This is expected and correct behavior for me. 
But I'd like to keep all the configuration and build parameters in `GebConfig.groovy` file.

So two questions here:

1. Now, if I need to get GebConfig property in my code, I use `browser.getConfig().getRawConfig().get("contextPath")`. Is it proper call or there is better way to get params from config in tests' code?
2. How to implement passing Jenkins job's parameters to Geb configuration? 
   I got only the idea to search for it in `System.getenv()` first:

   ```
   public String getProperty(String name) {
       Map<String, String> systemEnv = System.getenv();
       return systemEnv.get(name) ?: browser.config.rawConfig.get(name);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

All build tools accept -DvarName=varValue to pass properties into GebConfig.
[Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985395/gradle-gebconfig-groovy-parameterized), [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840678/grails-geb-getting-parameters-from-commandline), and [Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776135/how-to-pass-parameters-for-a-ant-script-which-is-invoked-via-shell-script). So you'd pass that variable through in your Jenkins Build step

Edit: Below is in my GebConfig which handles default values vs passed in variables

```
System.setProperty("geb.env.username", System.getProperty("geb.env.username", 'test'))
```

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know, after passing a property via -DvarName=varValue I will need to describe it in duild gradle by calling systemProperty("varName", project.varName). And then I am able to use it in GebConfig as System.getProperty("varName"). My question is how to replace the value of varName in GebConfig automatically if it was passed via -D parameter or exists in System.getEnv()